# In perl what does -f mean in an if statement?

Tags: perl

```
 my $Path = $_[0];
 return "" if(not $Path or not -f $Path);
```

I am going through a perl file and not able to understand what the -f option means
What does not -f mean ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `-f` operator tests whether its operand is a regular file, rather than a directory, a symbolic link, or another special file.

All operators starting with a `-` are called file test operators and are usually found in shell-scripting languages as well. They are unary operators (taking just one operand), like `!` or `~` are unary operators.

Comment: [For more info on file operators, see here.](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

Answer (score 8):

```
-r   readable
-w   writable
-x   executable
-o   owned by  user
-R   readable by this  user or group
-W   writable by user or group
-X   executable by this  user or group
-O   owned by this  user
-e   File or directory name exists
-z   File exists and has zero size
-s   exists and has nonzero size (the value is the size in bytes)
-f   plain file
-d   directory
-l   symbolic link
-S   socket
```